# User Stories keep being added to "General User Stories" despite being created under an use case

Tags: uml, agile-project-management, visual-paradigm

After drawing the following UC Diagram, I right click on an use case and send it to the backlog

[image]

It appears as a new activity in the product backlog, like this:

[image]

So I move it to the board and create a task and an epic underneath:

[image]

Then I go on creating the User Stories for the new topic called "Plugin Deployment":

[image]

Everything works great so far, I can even edit the conversation and confirmation items:

[image]

**The problem**

As soon as I activate the tab "scenario", the current story, which so far I thought I associated with the "Plugin Deployment" use case, appears under a new model "General User Stories":

[image]

What can I do to organize the stories inside my model in the proper way? What does Visual Paradigm 14.1 Professional Edition expect from me? Any ways to circumvent this problem? I don't want to end up with hundreds of user stories there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user stories in Visual Paradigm actually is a kind of server side model where the modifications are directly synchronized to server. They should not be showing in Model Explorer since it is only for showing the model element located within the local project file. The linkage between model element and user story are established with the User Activity in story map via the Send to Product Backlog (which you already did). You can always navigate from model elements in diagram to User Activity created to story map using the Send to Product Backlog via the Open in Scrum resource icon, and then traverse down to User Task, Epic and then to User Story.

BTW the latest patch build of v14.1 SP1 already enhanced the Model Explorer to hide out the user stories. This should to avoid confusion to user. You can contact [Visual Paradigm Support Team](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/) for details about how to update the software to latest patch build.